# Cannot resolve the collation conflict between temp table and sys.objects

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The following T-SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE #exclude(name VARCHAR(256))
INSERT INTO #exclude VALUES('someprefix_someprocedure')

SELECT 'someschema.' + sys.objects.name
FROM sys.objects
  LEFT JOIN #exclude ON sys.objects.name = #exclude.name
WHERE sys.objects.name LIKE 'someprefix_%'
  AND type IN ('FN', 'TR', 'P')
  AND #exclude.name IS NULL
ORDER BY sys.objects.name ASC
```

Returns this error:

> **Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 4**
>
> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between `Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS` and `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` in the equal to operation.

I tried appending this to the query, but it still returns the same error:

```
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ASC
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to any field that produces this error, in the WHERE or ON (JOIN) Clause:
`COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT`.

e.g. (Your Question Above)

```
CREATE TABLE #exclude(name VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO #exclude VALUES('someprefix_someprocedure')

SELECT 'someschema.' + sys.objects.name
FROM sys.objects
  LEFT JOIN #exclude ON sys.objects.name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = #exclude.name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
WHERE sys.objects.name LIKE 'someprefix_%'
  AND type IN ('FN', 'TR', 'P')
  AND #exclude.name IS NULL
ORDER BY sys.objects.name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the table `#exclude`, you'll need to add `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` to any text fields - as below:

```
CREATE TABLE #exclude(name VARCHAR(256) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT NULL)
INSERT INTO #exclude VALUES('someprefix_someprocedure')

SELECT 'someschema.' + sys.objects.name
FROM sys.objects
  LEFT JOIN #exclude ON sys.objects.name = #exclude.name
WHERE sys.objects.name LIKE 'someprefix_%'
  AND type IN ('FN', 'TR', 'P')
  AND #exclude.name IS NULL
ORDER BY sys.objects.name ASC
```