# SSRS Update Run Time of Schedule from Back End

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Hello I have about 900+ subscriptions that I would like to update to run at 10 AM instead of 7 AM. I cannot find on the reporting server or in my many google searches what field I need to update.

To get general data I am using the below query. It seems there must be a field somewhere holding the Run Time, probably in XML?

```
USE reportserver
GO

select  c.Name,
s.StartDate,
s.NextRunTime,
s.LastRunTime,
s.EndDate,
s.RecurrenceType,
s.LastRunStatus,
s.MinutesInterval,
s.DaysInterval,
s.WeeksInterval,
s.DaysOfWeek,
s.DaysOfMonth,
s.[Month],
s.MonthlyWeek
from    dbo.catalog c with (nolock)
inner join  dbo.ReportSchedule rs
on  rs.ReportID = c.ItemID
inner join  dbo.Schedule s with (nolock)
on  rs.ScheduleID = s.ScheduleID
where ISNULL(s.ENDDATE,'2050-01-01') >= '2016-01-01'
order by    c.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Those subscriptions run on a recurring basis. The logic to determine the next run time probably uses a query similar to [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25943877/is-there-a-way-to-query-future-ssrs-subscription-schedules).

It would be nice if there was a `NextCalculatedRunDate` field, however, the logic probably fires every time the agent runs to send subscriptions which would render the next run field useless.

Based on the recurring types and values, you can probably predict the next run time. I bet that subscription service agent runs in a range like every 5-30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but what I was thinking was. I setup a subscription to run on the 1st of every month at 10 AM . I can find where the 1st of every month is listed, but not the 10 AM. If it is recalculated each time it must still store the 10 AM somewhere right?

Comment: Then perhaps it is the LastRunTime field. I would think the timing is a time of day type calculation and based on the last run time of day. Can you switch to  test server and modify that value and see what happens?