# Amend SSRS Subscriptions with T-SQL

Tags: ssrs-2012

Can existing SSRS Subscriptions be amended using T-SQL? I have a scenario where many subscriptions failed to send due to a server error. I want to move all of them to a new date/time, and afterwards move them all back again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I have issues with reports not running, I usually refire the subscription using EXEC dbo.AddEvent with the subscription ID.

```
SELECT e.name
   , e.path
   , d.description
   , a.SubscriptionID
   , laststatus
   , LastRunTime
   , date_modified
   , 'EXEC dbo.AddEvent @EventType = ''TimedSubscription'', @EventData = '' ' + CAST(a.SubscriptionID AS VARCHAR(100)) + ''''
FROM 
ReportServer.dbo.ReportSchedule a 
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs b ON CAST(a.ScheduleID AS NVARCHAR(200)) = b.name
JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions d  ON a.SubscriptionID = d.SubscriptionID
JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Catalog e ON d.report_oid = e.itemid
WHERE d.LastStatus LIKE 'Fail%'
    AND eventtype = 'TimedSubscription'
ORDER BY e.name
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question...

> **Can existing SSRS Subscriptions be amended using T-SQL?**

I am not sure if you can change the subscription with TSQL.  I have extracted the subscriptions with SQL... see this answer I posted with SQL query: [is there a way to query future SSRS subscription schedules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25943877/is-there-a-way-to-query-future-ssrs-subscription-schedules/52429269#52429269).

I have been playing around with **`PowerShell`** a lot recently for Administative automation scripting.  There is a **`ReportingServicesTools module`** you can install for PowerShell [from Microsoft on Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/ReportingServicesTools).  I would recommend that you try learning that.  It looks cool in my opinion,  and so far with my testing it seems to have some promising capabilities.

- [RedGlue: Installing ReportingServicesTools for Powershell](http://redglue.eu/ssrs-report-deployment-made-easy-700-times-faster/)
- [RedGlue: Powershell and SSRS Subscriptions](http://redglue.eu/does-that-copy-subscriptions-too-now-it-does-new-powershell-ssrs-commands/) or [SQL Server Central: Powershell and SSRS Subscriptions](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/cl%C3%A1udio-silva/2017/07/27/does-that-copy-subscriptions-too-now-it-does-new-powershell-ssrs-commands/)

*NOTE: I have Windows 7 which comes with Powershell Version 2.  I had to upgrade my Powershell to Version 4 to install the RS module using these instructions: 1) [MS Installing Windows PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-windows-powershell?view=powershell-6), 2) [How to check the PowerShell version & install a new version](https://mikefrobbins.com/2015/01/08/how-to-check-the-powershell-version-and-install-a-new-version/).  To check your version of Powershell execute either of these commands... `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` or `$psversiontable`, as seen in this post: [Determine installed PowerShell version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825585/determine-installed-powershell-version).*

> **I want to move all of them to a new date/time, and afterwards move
>   them all back again.**

The purpose of PowerShell is not only to view objects, but that you can also modify them.

The RSTools posh module has quite a few relevant cmdlets including: `Get-RsSubscripton`, `Set-RsSubscripton`, `Copy-RsSubscripton`, `Export-RsSubscripton`, `Import-RsSubscripton`, `New-RsSubscripton`, `Remove-RsSubscripton`.  Below I have demoed the `Help` and the `Subscription Properties` on the server based a on single folder using **GET** and **SET**.

The **Set-RsSubscription** cmdlet has parameters to let you easily change the subscription properties **StartDateTime**, **EndDate**, **Owner**.  And then there is the parameter **SubProperties**, not sure at this point what this one is.

---

### **DEMO: Powershell Code**

***Declare variables***

```
$reportServerUri_src = "http://gcod049/ReportServer"
$reportServerUri_tgt = "http://gcod050/ReportServer"
```

***Find The Subscriptions (one folder returns 2 subscriptions.. 'd8e0decf-86f3-49cb-896f-3af644be1be3' and '4c1539c4-9e0f-42c4-aace-b493c96ec2e4')***

```
Get-RsSubscription -ReportServerUri $reportServerUri_src -RsItem "/fsqa"
```

***Change the STARTDATETIME For A Specific Subscription***

```
Get-RsSubscription -ReportServerUri $reportServerUri_src -Path "/fsqa" | Where-Object {$_.SubscriptionId -eq '4c1539c4-9e0f-42c4-aace-b493c96ec2e4'} | Set-RsSubscription -StartDateTime "2/13/2019 1:20pm" -verbose
```

***Change the STARTDATETIME For An Entire Folder***

```
Get-RsSubscription -ReportServerUri $reportServerUri_src -Path "/fsqa" |  Set-RsSubscription -StartDateTime "2/13/2019 1:20pm" -verbose
```

***(BONUS) Move all subscriptions from one server folder to another (gcod050 "/fsqa" to gcod049 "/fsqa")***

--*Move Subscriptions (From/To Folder)*

NOTE, 2/13/19 : [A bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/ReportingServicesTools/issues/172) is being worked out on this right now.

```
Get-RsSubscription -ReportServerUri $reportServerUri_src -RsItem "/fsqa" | Copy-RsSubscription -ReportServerUri $reportServerUri_tgt -RsItem "/fsqa" -verbose
```

--*Create Folder*

```
New-RsFolder -ReportServerUri $reportServerUri_tgt -RsFolder '/' -FolderName 'FSQA' -Description 'Reports for Food Saftey Quality Asurance department' -Verbose

--- Messages output from '-Verbose' parameter ---
VERBOSE: Establishing proxy connection to http://gcod050/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx...
VERBOSE: Creating folder FSQA...
VERBOSE: Folder FSQA created successfully!
```

--*Move Reports (From/To Folder)*

Well... I couldn't quite figure out the PS module command to move a report From Server-A to Server-B.  The commands to published reports via Powershell all appear to work with local files ([Link Name: Article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4738/powershell-commands-for-sql-server-reporting-services/)).  Here is an easy-to-use tool you can download for moving reports from ServerA to ServerB, [SSRS 2008 R2 to SSRS 2016 Migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439854/ssrs-2008-r2-to-ssrs-2016-migration/52705179#52705179).

```
NOTE:
The "Content" cmdlets (based upon the documentation) appear to move files from/to a directory, instead of ServerA to ServerB

CMD:
get-command -module ReportingServicesTools *cont*

OUTPUT:
CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName
-----------     ----                                               ----------
Function        Get-RsFolderContent                                ReportingServicesTools
Function        Out-RsFolderContent                                ReportingServicesTools
Function        Out-RsRestFolderContent                            ReportingServicesTools
Function        Write-RsFolderContent                              ReportingServicesTools
Function        Write-RsRestFolderContent                          ReportingServicesTools
```

### **DEMO: Screenshot**

*POSH_Get-RsSubscription -ReportServerUri $reportServerUri -Path fsqa.png*

```
Get-RsSubscription -ReportServerUri $reportServerUri -Path "/fsqa"
```

[image]

*POSH_get-help get-RsSubscription.png*

```
get-help Get-RsSubscription
```

[image]

*POSH_Get-Help Set-RsSubscription -detailed*

```
Get-Help Set-RsSubscription -detailed
```

[image]

*POSH_Get-Help Copy-RsSubscription.png*

```
Get-Help Copy-RsSubscription
```

[image]

POSH_Get-Command -Module ReportingServicesTools.png

```
Get-Command -Module ReportingServicesTools
```

[image]

---

### ***UPDATE Tue 02/12/2019 16:27:33.22***

I found another article from AUG 2017 which talks about how to *modify* the SSRS Subscription programatically also via PowerShell-- [Warrenestes.com "Update Multiple SSRS Subscriptions"](https://www.warrenestes.com/update-multiple-ssrs-subscriptions/).  On his site he has developed his own PoSH functions using New-WebServiceProxy, which looked a bit complicated to me.  But he did say this in his article about cmdlet SET-RSSUBSCRIPTION:

```
Edit:  This is now part of the official Microsoft ReportingServicesTools PowerShell module. 
This a brand new function, which was recently renamed from Update to Set-RsSubscription!!!!!.
```

and he said this ...

```
I did find a post on dba.stackexchange referencing the real [EndDate] from a column 
in **dbo.Subscritions** called… wait for the descriptive name... **[MatchData]**!
```